# Не сортируются колонки, что может быть не так?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    th {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    th:hover {
      background: yellow;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table id="grid">
    <thead id='header'>
      <tr>
        <th data-type="number">Возраст</th>
        <th data-type="string">Имя</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Вася</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Петя</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>Женя</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>Маша</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Илья</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <script>
    function sortColumn(colNum, type){
      let body = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
      document.removeChild(body);
      let rows = [].slice.call(body.rows);
      
      let sortFunction;
      
      switch(type){
        case 'number':
          sortFunction = function(A, B){
            return A.cells[colNum].innerHTML - B.cell[colNum].innerHTML;
          };
          
        case 'string':
          sortFunction = function(A, B){
            return A.cells[colNum].innerHTML > B.cell[colNum].innerHTML;
          }
      }
      
      rows.sort(sortFunction);
      
      for(let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
        body.appendChild(rows[i]);
      }
      
      document.querySelector('grid').appendChild(body);
    }
    
    let thead = document.querySelector('#header');
    
    thead.addEventListener('click', function(event){
      if (event.target.tagName != 'th') return;
      let cellIndex = event.target.cellIndex;
      let typeColumn = event.target.getAttribute('data-type');
      
      sortColumn(cellIndex, typeColumn);
    });
    
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Сразу в глаза бросается `if (event.target.tagName != 'th') return;`

Comment: Рустам, всё равно не сортирует

Comment: 1. Зачем удалять? `document.removeChild(body);` непонятно... 
2. `return A.cells[colNum].innerHTML > B.cells[colNum].innerHTML;` тут вместо `B.cell[colNum].innerHTML;` надо так `B.cells[colNum].innerHTML;`
3. Вместо `document.querySelector('grid')` надо так: `document.querySelector('#grid')`

Comment: Спасибо, только сейчас с этим прозрел. Гребаная невнимательность